# How To Inject AuthenticationManager using Java Configuration in a Custom Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm using Spring Security 3.2 and Spring 4.0.1

I'm working on converting an xml config into a Java config. When I annotate `AuthenticationManager` with `@Autowired` in my Filter, I'm getting an exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I've tried injecting `AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean` but that also fails with a similar exception.

Here is the XML configuration I'm working from

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans ...>
    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http
            realm="Protected API"
            use-expressions="true"
            auto-config="false"
            create-session="stateless"
            entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
            authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="tokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="tokenFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
        <security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('user')"/>
        <security:intercept-url method="PUT" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')"/>
        <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')"/>
        <security:intercept-url method="DELETE" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean class="com.unsubcentral.security.TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
          id="tokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/rest/user/authenticate"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the Java Config I'm attempting

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                    .and();
        //TODO: Custom Filters
    }
}
```

And this is the Custom Filter class. The line giving me trouble is the setter for AuthenticationManager

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    @Autowired
    public TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(@Value("/rest/useAuthenticationManagerr/authenticate") String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
      ...
    }

    private String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter("password");
    }

    private String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter("username");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what the Autowired do right above an Override ? I have never seen this before. What is wired in with this ?

Comment: How did you added your custom filter? I made my own filter and Authentication provider. But I don't know how to configure them to work together. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502589/spring-boot-hmac-authentication-how-to-add-custom-authenticationprovider-and-a

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Override method `authenticationManagerBean` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to expose the AuthenticationManager built using `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` as a Spring bean:

For example:

```
   @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
```

Comment: @qxixp "to expose the AuthenticationManager built using configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) as a Spring bean"

Comment: @Roger, why do we need to manually expose the AuthenticationManager?

Comment: @qxixp you can only Autowire a spring managed bean. If its not exposed as a bean, you cannot Autowire it.

Comment: The super method is not a Bean, then Override it and add Bean annotation.

Comment: What really helped me of this answer is the "name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER". Without it, it doesn't work at least in my environment.

Comment: Using this I can't login it create 401. But the same error I have in my test environment is gone. I also have 401 in my test environment.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when I had a StackOverflowException in this configuration today..

Comment: this way does not work for customized filter in spring security oauth2 ,`@Bean super.authenticationManagerBean()` like this will not build  the `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService`  and `DaoAuthenticationProvider`  it's  different from the way `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class)`

Comment: If you're looking for a Spring Security 5 way of doing this, I posted my findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494848/2220753

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Angular University said above you may want to use **@Import** to aggregate @Configuration classes to the other class (AuthenticationController in my case) :

```
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
//some logic
}
```

Spring doc about Aggregating @Configuration classes with @Import: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I @Bean'ed AuthenticationManager and @Autowired it in same class then needed to activate circular references but that is rather as for CDI.

Comment: Me, too, but there's a workaround: Instead of @Autowiring , you can dynamically resolve the bean if you Autowired the BeanFactory: ```private AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
    if (this.authenticationManager == null) {
      this.authenticationManager = beanFactory.getBean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER, AuthenticationManager.class);
    }
    return this.authenticationManager;
  }
```