# How to wire AuthenticationManager for Spring AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

I have a class derived from AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter in my Spring Security Filter Chain. The purpose of this filter is to massage role data left in a special Principal object by a corporate authentication service into a Collection so SpringSecurity can use them.

However, I cannot get past this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager must be set
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:97) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
```

I am using Java config, not XML config. My code following the example of [How To Inject AuthenticationManager using Java Configuration in a Custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter) is as follows:

1. the security configurer adaptor

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class MyWebSecurityAdaptor extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       ...
       @Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManager")
       @Override
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }
   }
   ```
2. The filter class itself:

   ```
   @Component
   public class MyPreauthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {


           ...
       @Autowired
       @Override
       public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
           super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
       }   
   }
   ```

If instead of the code in Item 1 above, I try the following:

```
    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception   
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
```

Then the error changes.

It then becomes:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate}

I guess that makes sense, this way does not define a bean. But then why didn't the original way, which DID define a bean, fail?

Comment: You must have defined somehwere on your code the authenticationManager which manages the authentication activity and thats the ben you have to supply to your MyPreauthFilter class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding 'myAuthernticationManager' to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. Add this directly to you filter class and autowire it.

```
@Autowired
@Override
public void setMyAuthenticationManager(MyAuthenticationManager myAuthenticationManager) {
    this.myAuthenticationManager  = myAuthenticationManager;
    super.setAuthenticationManager(this.myAuthenticationManager);
}
```

Remove all the code related to myAuthenticationManager from your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.