# Spring required a bean of type 'AuthenticationManager'

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I have been trying to follow a tutorial found [HERE](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/02/15/single-sign-on-in-spring-boot-applications-with-spring-security-oauth/) for setting up a demo to help me understand SSO on my local machine before implementing in another project. I have run into a problem that has left me stuck. I receive and error telling me to add a bean. Please let me know what code I am missing.  I cannot get the program to run.

**Tree of file system**

[image]

**AuthApplication.java**

```
package com.spud.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("foo").secret("bar")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("user_info")
                    .autoApprove(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.spud.controllers;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/sso-server
```

**Error Given** (not full console output from run but this is the error)

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.spud.auth.AuthApplication$OAuth2Config required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Inject AuthenticationManager using Java Configuration in a Custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to expose the `AuthenticationManager` as spring bean described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639553/7246467).

Comment: I should have mentioned I looked at a few other related posts, including the post you linked me. However 4:00am rolled around and I guess my reading skills went wack. I humored you and read that one again.

This time, I realized "Of course it wont work putting it in the OAuth2Config class". I implemented it in the correct class and it works. This is a duplicate question then. Thank you and my apologies.

Comment: No problem. I flagged the question as duplicated.