# Could Not Defining Bean Type and Autowired is Null

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

i have some problem while i wanna using my service on Authentication Filter in java. here my code

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authManager;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    this.authManager = authManager;

    super.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    User user = new User();

    try {
        Object req = request.getInputStream();
        user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return authManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUname(), user.getPass()));

}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String secretKey = "$2y$18$1d12QDK72RFixzHcDqKYjODHA36NAsKm1RIu5V1DsgbPJAxvH0R22";
    SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKey.getBytes());
    long expiredDate = 900000000;

    String tokenStr = Jwts.builder().signWith(key).setSubject(authResult.getName())
            .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiredDate)).compact();

    UserHelper usr = new UserHelper();
    User u = new User();
    System.out.println(authResult.getName());
    String uname = authResult.getName();
    System.out.println(uname);
    try {
        u = userService.findByUname(uname, uname);
        usr.setUser(u);
        usr.setToken(tokenStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().append("{\"token\":\"" + tokenStr + "\"}");

}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());

}
```

and the error message is

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.lawencon.security.AuthenticationFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

i try to use @Autowired, and @ Bean before constructor but the Annotations have dissallowed location.
for this case i wanna send response jwt and roles name

if i use bean annotations on this code

```
@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    this.authManager = authManager;

    super.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
}
```

the annotations is disallowed location

Comment: Auth Manager is the interface class, and I call it in the constructor of Auth Filter

Comment: You need to create a bean for that class..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473634/spring-required-a-bean-of-type-authenticationmanager

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu 
I've tried the method in the thread, but the bean annotation error disallowed the location

Comment: Add the code where you are trying to create a bean which is giving `disallowed` error

Comment: i just updated bean disallowed location error while add bean annotation

Answer (score 0):

It is said, that you should have default constructor in your class

public AuthenticationFilter(){
}

Answer (score 0):

`@Bean` annotation can not be used on a `constructor` which is why you are getting `disallowed` error.

You need to create a new class as below

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }

}
```