# Need help defining a bean with spring

Tags: java, spring, security, intellij-idea

I have searched the web for solutions but have not found any. This is my last resort.

2018-04-29 16:31:57.743  WARN 71317 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

CLASS:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("ClientId")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true);
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
}
```

CLASS:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
}

@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter . You should override method `authenticationManagerBean` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: @Bedla Yes, i have. I've tried to use the exact same method as suggested but then i get this error when trying to run the application :

Comment: @Bedla org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?