# Spring Boot AuthenticationManagerBean does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication

In my project when I am trying to define the bean for `AuthenticationManager` by overriding the `AuthenticationManagerBean()` method it is showing the below error,

> `The method authenticationManagerBean() of type SecurityConfiguration must override or implement a supertype method`

While the method I am defining is given below,

```
 @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
 @Override
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }
```

My entire `SecurityConfiguaration` class is given below,

```
package com.toorjaridwan.introvertreadersauth.Configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.toorjaridwan.introvertreadersauth.Service.UserDetailService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailService userDetailService;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

       @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
       @Override
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

In a previous project which used Spring Boot version **2.1.9**, everything went smoothly, no issue at all. Now I am using Spring Boot version **2.2.6**. I do not know if it is the reason.

When searching for solution I came across [this](https://community.pivotal.io/s/question/0D50e00005IChgDCAT/how-to-pass-a-custom-authenticationmanagerbean-to-the-basicauthenticationfilter?language=en_US) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639553/9707804). I found things to be as similar as I did.

I am running a 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Java version 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding

```
extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

to your configuration class

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is now deprecated, what do we do now that the security config doesn't extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: @PhongPhuong Read up on this document, https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: I did look at that but there bits and pieces of code missing in the examples.

I followed this and fixed the AuthenticationManagerBean():
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381114/spring-security-upgrading-the-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring