# Spring Security: Upgrading the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to update the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as it has been deprecated. The class is configured as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UsuariService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

Now without the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I redefine the same class like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UsuariService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        return builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder()).and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': 
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [cit/base/app/security/WebSecurityConfig.class]: 
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
  Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@3fdc705c to already built object
```

I would appreciate any kind of help that would be most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might help if you replace the two `@Autowired` fields with parameter injection into the `@Bean` methods instead.

Comment: I am doing the exact thing, trying to update the WebSecurityConfig. I have found this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter. I don't really know how to update my methods according to it but maybe you do. Hope it helps!

Comment: For anyone looking for an example, I found this https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/fix-websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated. Hope it helps!!

Comment: More here for anyone using JWT filter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281032/spring-security-exposing-authenticationmanager-without-websecurityconfigureradap

Answer (score 78):

I have managed to update the methods. This is the `WebSecurityConfig` class, and the methods are modified in the following way:

```java
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

has become

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

In the old version you inject `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, set `userDetailsService`, `passwordEncoder` and build it. But `authenticationManager` is already created in this step. It is created the way we wanted (with `userDetailsService` and the `passwordEncoder`).

Next, the `configure()` method for `HttpSecurity` is replaced by `filterChain` method as it is explained on the official site:

- https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter.

```java
import com.myproject.UrlMapping;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
   private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

   private final AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter;

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
       return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
   }

   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
               .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(UrlMapping.AUTH + UrlMapping.SIGN_UP).permitAll()
               .antMatchers(UrlMapping.AUTH + UrlMapping.LOGIN).permitAll()
               .antMatchers(UrlMapping.VALIDATE_JWT).permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();

       http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

       return http.build();
   }

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
       return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
           @Override
           public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
               registry.addMapping("/**")
                       .allowedMethods("*");
           }
       };
   }
}
```

I have added this in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
```

Comment: Hmm, struggeling with my old approach using JWTAuthenticationFilter. Wehre does the AuthTokenManager come from?

Comment: this answer contains some faulty information. If you declare a `@Bean` there is no need to set the classes manually in the builder. Thats the whole point of a dependency injection framwork, spring will automatically inject the beans into the classes that need them. So the first declared code part of this answer is completely unneeded and never needed to be included in the first place. And the second part is also unneeded. The framework will automatically create an AuthenticationManager for you Downvoted

Comment: @Toerktumlare would you care to post an answer using something that is not in your opinion "faulty"?

Comment: Sure i can or i could give you a chance to correct your answer. But if you wish for me to write an answer i could do that.

Comment: The solution in this answer seems to cause a bean cycle to form. See [#11792](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11792). The blog post detailing [deprecation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) has an example of the suggested approach.

Comment: So the usersDetailService is obsolete to?

Answer (score 18):

I hope this configuration will work for `UserDetailsService`, `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and `AuthenticationManager`.

```java
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/account/register", "/api/v1/account/auth").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountService.findAccountByEmail(email);
        return new UserPrincipalImp(account);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

change your file like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The complete implementation of SecurityConfig class without extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is as follows.

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
            // We don't need CSRF for this example
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    // don't authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                    // store user's state.
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return httpSecurity.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
            return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi!
May I ask you how did you implement: "JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" because I want to handle errors when I get wrong/expired... jwt

Comment: You can take a look at my repository for the implementation of Jwt. [Spring Boot app with Jwt](https://github.com/yashnmodi/rajblowplast-digital)

Comment: this implementation is faulty, as spring security already has a customizable jwtfilter so implementing one is bad practice

Comment: @Toerktumlare don't you have an example code?

Comment: why didn't you just read the spring security documentation? Its on theirr website, and all you needed to do was to search the docs for "JWT" https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Comment: @Toerktumlare you're right, but sometimes there are cases of using JWT without OAuth2.

Comment: @Toerktumlare could you please provide some example of out-of-the-box solution with new Spring Security? I was not able to find anything. EVERY example in the Inernet describes custom implementations. Also, I didn't find anything in Spring Docs (regarding Username and Password authentication)

Comment: Use FormLogin and then implement a `authenticationSuccessHandler` Where you create your JWT using nimbus. And then if you want to implement the handling of JWTs you can follow this https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1 spring security has lots of ”username/password” authentican models described in the chapter ”Authentication” and a full solution for handling JWT

Comment: Why are you autowiring userDetailService? you are not using it

Answer (score 4):

In Spring Security 6 there are a couple more changes

- @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity is now deprecated, use **@EnableMethodSecurity**
- antMatchers cannot be used, use **requestMatchers**
- Method configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) doesn't work, refer to Gloria's answer to set JDBC Authentication

**Code with Spring Boot 2.x**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/readiness_check").permitAll().antMatchers("/liveness_check").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/_ah/start").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

**Code with Spring Boot 3.1.13**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;





@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        //securedEnabled = true,
        //jsr250Enabled =true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter;
    
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
             http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .exceptionHandling(exp -> exp.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/readiness_check").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/liveness_check").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/_ah/start").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated());
            
            
            http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            
            return http.build();
    }
    

    
}
```

JWT creation also needs to be changed as jjwt dependency doesn't work. [This page can be referred](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#jws-create-key)

[Spring Security Reference doc](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 1):

- security config

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        int rounds = 12;
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(rounds);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                /*.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")*/
                .requestMatchers("/user/**", "/user/info/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);;

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        List<AuthenticationProvider> providers =  List.of(authProvider);

        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }
}
```

- service

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        final CustomerModel customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(username); /*email*/

        Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(new UserRole("USER"));
        roles.add(new UserRole("ADMIN"));

        if (customer == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        String email = customer.email();
        String password = customer.password();

        return User
                .withUsername(email)
                .password(password)
                /*.roles("USER")*/ /*Into a Security filter must be expression -> hasRole()*/
        
                .authorities(convertAuthorities(roles))
                .build();
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> convertAuthorities(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new HashSet<>();
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.nameRole()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: `AuthenticationManager` could be a local variable, instead of a bean: to have custom `UserDetailsService` for different `SecurityFilterChain`.

Answer (score 1):

The below code demonstrates the possible solution of implementing Spring Security  With Basic Authentication *without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*.
Here, in the old version we inject **AuthenticationManagerBuilder**, set **userDetailsService**, **passwordEncoder** and build it. But **AuthenticationManager** is created the way we wanted (with userDetailsService and the passwordEncoder).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disabling csrf since we won't use form login
                .csrf().disable()
                // setting stateless session, because we choose to implement Rest API
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // giving permission to every request for /login endpoint
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                // for everything else, the user has to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in my case, the simplest way is to pass your userDetailService class directly in the SecurityFilterChain function.

Note :
`http.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);`

BCryptPasswordEncoder class  automicaly get autowired  as password Encoder, if @Bean method is avilable in configration.

```
@Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
```

Code :

```
package com.example.blogapi.config;

import com.example.blogapi.security.CustomUserDetailService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        (authz) -> authz.anyRequest()
                                .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }





}
```

Comment: no the simplest way is to just provide a bean of a UserDetailsService to the framework just like you are doing with bcrypt and the framework will handle the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of exposing Spring Actuator with a custom `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 1)
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, SecurityConfig secCfg) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
        // auth.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info")).permitAll();
        auth.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class), EndpointRequest.to(InfoEndpoint.class)).permitAll();
        auth.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN");
    });
    http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    final InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemUserDb = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    for (SecurityConfig.User user : secCfg.getUsers()) {
        final UserDetails userDetails = User
                .withUsername(user.getName())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles(user.getRoles().toArray(String[]::new))
                .build();
        inMemUserDb.createUser(userDetails);
    }
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(inMemUserDb);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(inMemUserDb);
    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    final AuthenticationManager authManager = authManagerBuilder.build();
    http.authenticationManager(authManager);
    return http.build();
}
```

It demonstrates that many Spring classes could be instantiated via a constructor injection instead of a bean injection: this allows to create lots of independent custom `SecurityFilterChain` without polluting a bean factory (so auto-configuration won't build magical unexpected beans).

Take a look at magic: `@Order` (to give a chanse for `http.securityMatcher` to match a request before another or `*` filter chain) & `getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)` (IDK why we need it, instead of getting as an injected bean).

Answer (score -1):

depends on deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

for "Basic Authentication" we can use this snippet code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(HttpBasicConfigurer::withDefaults)
            .and().build();
    }
}
```