# How to transform deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: spring-boot, role-base-authorization

I'm working on a project and my problem is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. It's doesn't work. It's say "The type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated" How to transform deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to SecurityFilterChain? Can you help me please? I don't know what to do

Here is my WebSecurityConfig class :

```
package com.projectuas.controller;
import com.projectuas.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
         
        return authProvider;
    }


@Overide
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Overide
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/new").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/edit/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        ;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security: Upgrading the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381114/spring-security-upgrading-the-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter we need to override following methods.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // http security configuration         
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {         
    // web security configuration         
}
```

If we want to do this without using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter we should replace them by registering these beans.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
}
 
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
     
}
```

**Example**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailService)
        throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .and()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/new").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/edit/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
    ;

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**");
}
```

}