# How do i re-write this after WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring and was learning how to use JWT from a [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/VVn9OG9nfH0) and in that tutorial they were extending the security configuration with this deprecated abstract class i saw the documentation and they are using beans now but i am not getting how i can replicate this exact code with beans, i will really be gratefull if i can get some help in that.

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look, I think there is enough information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381114/spring-security-upgrading-the-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: i also have this bit of code previously i was taking the authentication manager from the suer class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` now from where i can use...
i need it for `http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFIter(authenticationManager()));`
```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```
here previously i was getting the `authenticationManager` from `super.authenticationManagerBean()` but now how can i get it

Comment: try
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}