# Getting error as "The method filterChain(HttpSecurity) of type SecurityConfig must override or implement a supertype method"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting error as
`The method filterChain(HttpSecurity) of type SecurityConfig must override or implement a supertype method`

My code are

`SecurityConfig.java`

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

   
    @Autowired private AuthSecurity filter;
    

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()              

.antMatchers("/prod/api/v1/open/status").permitAll()     

       .antMatchers("/prod/api/v1/open/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(
                            (request, response, authException) ->
                                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized")
                    )
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilter(filter);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`AuthSecurity.java`

```html
@Component
public class AuthSecurity extends OncePerRequestFilter{

        @Override
        @ResponseBody
        public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
                                         {
            String authHeader = response.getHeader("Authorization");
            
            if(authHeader != null && authHeader.length()>0 && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
            {
                String jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
                if(jwt == null || jwt.length()==0){
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid Token in Bearer Header");
            }
            else
            {             if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null && jwt.equals("asd123")){    SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        
                    }
                else{
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid Token");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to check if the Header token matches my personal token and if it is allow it to visit other endpoints.

The error log is

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method filterChain in com.company.framework.Security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.
```

I have just started working on Spring boot, so I am not able to understand the things that are going back in there. If you have any ideas or documentation to easily understand all these things, iT would be great.
Before questioning, I looked through
[Spring Security: Upgrading the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381114/spring-security-upgrading-the-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring)

But the solution there isn't working for me.

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle` / `pom.xml`? It looks like you are using an older version of Spring Security. For documentation resources please check the official Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html). You can view the correct documentation corresponding to your version on that page. Unfortunately, the question you linked to contains some bad practices and I would not recommend following their solution.