# Spring Security: How to inject the AuthenticationManager in a controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I was looking through similar questions, but did not find anything that helped:

In my spring security configuration class I configure my `AuthenticationManager` like this (to use a `UserDetailsService` implementation). I have read, that this should configure a global authentication manager to use.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    // Other things...

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

My question is: How to use it in a custom controller? If I try it like this ...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/perform_login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class LoginController {
    
    @Resource
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView login(

        // login logic using the authenticationManager
    }
    
}
```

... then it says, that no bean of type `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is available. So please help me out: Where is my misunderstanding? How can I actually use the `AuthenticationManager`?

Comment: Replace `@Autowired` with `@Override`, since you are implementing the `configure` method from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` superclass. --- You should remove `@Qualifier` too.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with Override too in the beginning. But I finally found the solution: I need to use Override AND add an extra bean method like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter