# Spring Security exposing AuthenticationManager without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying incoming Spring Boot 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT, which uses Spring Security 5.7.0, which deprecate `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I read [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), but I'm not sure to understand how I can expose the default implementation of `AuthenticationManager` to my JWT authorization filter.

The old `WebSecurityConfig`, using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (works fine) :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disable CSRF as we do not serve browser clients
                .csrf().disable()
                // allow access restriction using request matcher
                .authorizeRequests()
                // authenticate requests to GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
                // allow all other requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                // JWT authorization filter
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(getAuthenticationManager(), jwtTokenUtils))
                // make sure we use stateless session, session will not be used to store user's state
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

The new `WebSecurityConfig` :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http
                // disable CSRF as we do not serve browser clients
                .csrf().disable()
                // allow access restriction using request matcher
                .authorizeRequests()
                // authenticate requests to GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
                // allow all other requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                // JWT authorization filter
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, jwtTokenUtils))
                // make sure we use stateless session, session will not be used to store user's state
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

As you see I have no `AuthenticationManager` exposed bean anymore. I cannot get it from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. So I tried to get it directly from the `HttpSecurity` in the `filterChain` method, so I can pass it to my JWT filter directly.

But I still need an `AuthenticationManager` bean to be exposed to my `JWTAuthorizationFilter` :

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.config.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

How can I expose it?

Here is the JWT authorization filter (checks the token and authenticate the user, I have a custom `UserDetailsService` which do the credentials check in the database) :

```java
@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private final JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager, JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils) {
        super(authManager);
        this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // retrieve request authorization header
        final String authorizationHeader = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        // authorization header must be set and start with Bearer
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {

            // decode JWT token
            final JWTTokenPayload jwtTokenPayload = jwtTokenUtils.decodeToken(authorizationHeader);

            // if user e-mail has been retrieved correctly from the token and if user is not already authenticated
            if (jwtTokenPayload.getEmail() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                // authenticate user
                final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtTokenPayload.getEmail(), null, Collections.singletonList(jwtTokenPayload.getRole()));

                // set authentication in security context holder
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            } else {
                log.error("Valid token contains no user info");
            }
        }
        // no token specified
        else {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // pass request down the chain, except for OPTIONS requests
        if (!"OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT :

I realized I can manage to get the `authenticationManager` in my JWT filter using the method provided [in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1036063319), but still I need an `AuthenticationManager` to be exposed globally because I also need it in my controller.

Here is the authentication controller which need the `authenticationManager` to be injected :

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@Component
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody JWTRequest userRequest) {

        // try to authenticate user using specified credentials
        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userRequest.getEmail(), userRequest.getPassword()));

        // if authentication succeeded and is not anonymous
        if (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {

            // set authentication in security context holder
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            // get authorities, we should have only one role per member so simply get the first one
            final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = authentication.getAuthorities().iterator().next();

            // generate new JWT token
            final String jwtToken = jwtTokenUtils.generateToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), grantedAuthority);

            // return response containing the JWT token
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWTResponse(jwtToken));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    }

}
```

Comment: the solution to this problem is to STOP using a justom JWT filter when there is already a built in JWT filter in spring security, and it has had one since 2018. Please read oauth2/jwt chapter in the official spring security documentation. There is no reason whatsoever to have a custom jwt filter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I appreciate when downvoters don't hide. I would be happy to improve my question next time. The code was written before 2018, I'm in the process of updating it. It does not use OAuth 2, it's a very basic application that just needs a simple JWT to protect a GraphQL endpoint, I'm not sure it needs the whole OAuth 2 stuff. Also I think there can be many reasons to have a filter requiring an `AuthenticationManager`, apart from this specific case., Actually it's more like a generic question. Anyway, if you have any precise doc link or example, I'd be happy to check it out.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: `I'm not sure it needs the whole OAuth 2 ` For ALL OF YOU that is affraid because it says Oauth2 in the docs. This just shows that you have not read the oauth2 spec. The spec is huge and one part of the spec is how to LOGIN, but a small part of the spec is what is called `Resource Server` All of you that are supplying a JWT to your servers to just verify the signature and the authorize the user is FROM THE OAUTH2 SPEC. So stop saying "i dont want oauth2" because that is what you are all implementing, a part of the oauth2 specc without knowing it.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I think your comment is irrelevant. By any reason, he requires authenticationManager.

Comment: pointing out when people are building unsecure login implementations is never irrelevant. Using a token as a session bearer is unsecure. As pointed out in numerous blog posts, and in owasps documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want the AuthenticationManager bean to be in the spring context, you can use the following solution.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
     return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

This approach has solved the problem for me and you can inject AuthenticationManager wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that did not directly solve the problem because I still needed to pass the authentication manager to the JWT filter through its constructor, it cannot be autowired (needed in `super` call). But I managed to get from the `filterChain` method through `authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class))` and it seems to work fine. I accept your answer, and keep other answers for more details and alternatives. Best!

Answer (score 38):

### Local `AuthenticationManager`

*A* solution to be able to get and pass the `AuthenticationManager` (which you cannot get anymore from the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) to the filter, is to have a dedicated configurer which will be responsible for adding the filter. (This is inspired from the solution provided [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1036063319). Edit : and now officially in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-custom-dsls)).

Create a custom HTTP configurer :

```java
@Component
public class JWTHttpConfigurer extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<JWTHttpConfigurer, HttpSecurity> {

    private final JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    public JWTHttpConfigurer(JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils) {
        this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.antMatcher("/graphql").addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, jwtTokenUtils));
    }

}
```

Then simply apply it in the security config :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disable CSRF as we do not serve browser clients
                .csrf().disable()
                // allow access restriction using request matcher
                .authorizeRequests()
                // authenticate requests to GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
                // allow all other requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                // JWT authorization filter
                .apply(new JWTHttpConfigurer(jwtTokenUtils)).and()
                // make sure we use stateless session, session will not be used to store user's state
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

### Global `AuthenticationManager`

In some cases you need to expose the authentication manager globally so it is available anywhere in your application.

*A* solution to have the `AuthenticationManager` bean in the Spring context is to get it from the `AuthenticationConfiguration` which exports the authentication configuration (credits to Andrei Daneliuc's answer below) :

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Then if you need to retrieve it in your filter chain, you can use `authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class))`.

So the whole security config would be :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disable CSRF as we do not serve browser clients
                .csrf().disable()
                // match GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatcher("/graphql")
                // add JWT authorization filter
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)), jwtTokenUtils))
                // allow access restriction using request matcher
                .authorizeRequests()
                // authenticate requests to GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
                // allow all other requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                // make sure we use stateless session, session will not be used to store user's state
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

---

*Another* solution to expose an authentication manager globally is to use a custom `AuthenticationManager`, as a bean available to the entire application, which does quite the same thing as, in our case, the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` implementation (i.e. use the custom `UserDetailsService` to get user details from the database, verify the password using the configured `PasswordEncoder`, then return a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to present the `Authentication`) :

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final UserDetails userDetail = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        if (!passwordEncoder().matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), userDetail.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password");
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetail.getUsername(), userDetail.getPassword(), userDetail.getAuthorities());
    }

}
```

So that you can use it in the security config when adding the filter :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disable CSRF as we do not serve browser clients
                .csrf().disable()
                // match GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatcher("/graphql")
                // add JWT authorization filter
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(new CustomAuthenticationManager(), jwtTokenUtils))
                // allow access restriction using request matcher
                .authorizeRequests()
                // authenticate requests to GraphQL endpoint
                .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
                // allow all other requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                // make sure we use stateless session, session will not be used to store user's state
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

And it can be injected anywhere else in the application, i.e. in a controller :

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@Component
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody JWTRequest userRequest) {

        // try to authenticate user using specified credentials
        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userRequest.getEmail(), userRequest.getPassword()));

        // if authentication succeeded and is not anonymous
        if (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {

            // set authentication in security context holder
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            // get authorities, we should have only one role per member so simply get the first one
            final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = authentication.getAuthorities().iterator().next();

            // generate new JWT token
            final String jwtToken = jwtTokenUtils.generateToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), grantedAuthority);

            // return response containing the JWT token
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWTResponse(jwtToken));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    }

}
```

Note that you may want to also use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, to return a 401 instead of a 500 when `BadCredentialsException` is raised.

Comment: In CustomAuthenticationManager, this line looks suspicious/unclear to me `!passwordEncoder().matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), userDetail.getPassword())`. The first argument in matches(...) method accepts the raw password without encoding. But I think we are not advised to have password in decoded form.  Why would we ever initialize/configure Authentication object to have raw password?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed in by injecting the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` into the filter. I then make the filter implement `SmartInitializingSingleton` and call `getObject()` on the builder to obtain the `AuthenticationManager` in the `afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method.

More background on how I came up with this here: https://blog.trifork.com/2022/02/25/getting-out-of-a-codependent-relationship-or-how-i-moved-to-a-healthy-component-based-spring-security-configuration/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seem like a nice workaround :) I think I managed to get the `authenticationManager` in my JWT filter using [this solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1036063319), but I just realized I still need a globally exposed `AuthenticationManager` bean to be injected in my controller. I have updated the question.

Comment: writing custom security is bad practice. There is no reason to implement a custom JWT filter when there is a fully implemented filter already in spring security that follows the oauth2 rfc. This filter is fully tested, and run in 1000s of applications worldwide. Implementing "custom" security is a huge gamble and any fault in the implementation can put the entire applications data at risk. So no, custom security is bad practice, and thats why there are security standards.

Answer (score 1):

For those still experiencing issues, one of the contributors posted an example of a fix here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1036063319.

There are more examples of transitioning to Spring Security 5 here: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#ldap-authentication

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // you probably want a request matcher since you are using @Order
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .apply(customDsl());
        return http.build();
    }
}

public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilter(new TokenAuthFilter(authenticationManager));
    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }
}
```