# Spring Security: Global AuthenticationManager without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Im trying to get rid of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. The AuthenticationManager is configured like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class DefaultSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    } 
 

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
  throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
```

Now without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter i define the global  AuthenticationManager like this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class DefaultSecurityConfig  {

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
            return auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).and().build();
        }
```

And i get the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@536a79bd to already built object
```

Im using Spring Boot v2.6.4

I'm stuck here for a while i would appreciate any help

Comment: Note that calling `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` is redundant. If `userDetailsService` and `passwordEncoder` are beans, then Spring Security will pick them up automatically. Could you explain why you need to expose the `AuthenticationManager` bean? Depending on the usage there are different recommended solutions.

Comment: we are injecting the AuthenticationManager in Security services for authentication purposes like : 

`@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);`

Comment: It seems like that logic could be moved into a custom `Filter`. The filter could be applied in a custom DSL and the `AuthenticationManager` can be passed in from the DSL. See [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1036063319) on GitHub for an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security exposing AuthenticationManager without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281032/spring-security-exposing-authenticationmanager-without-websecurityconfigureradap)

Answer (score 17):

Replace

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
       return auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).and().build();
    }
```

by

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

In my project, I needed to use the `AuthenticationManager` in the Controller, to make a custom login. Then I declare:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/login")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginResource {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    ....
}
```

In `SecurityConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  {

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private final UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Then Works fine to me!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this section below.

Hope it works, working fine in my code

```
       @Bean
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                  .userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService)
                  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

100% tested. You may try.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok
public class YourConfigClass {
    private final UserDetailsService userService;
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;

    @Autowired
    void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    // OR use
    // Remove or comment out: private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```