# Authenticating without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, authorization, websecurity

I've been following issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605941/spring-security-global-authenticationmanager-without-the-websecurityconfigurera) one in order to figure out how to implement Authentication without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but my code simply fails to work.

This is my SecurityConfig class:

```
package com.authentication.take.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.authentication.take.services.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService,
            AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) {
        super();
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) 
    throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/yolo/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is that the /login route is being overriden somehow, and cannot be found. Therefore, when I post data to /login, it isn't interpreted because there is no form in that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `loginProcessingUrl()`

```
....
 http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/yolo/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/login")//or any another url ,this url accept just post request
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I still have another problem though. When I am not logged in, all my requests return "404, /login not found" instead of "403: Forbidden". I think Spring is not locating the default login.html file, even though logging in works fine.