# I can't join into html from controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I wrote a restful spring security application, when I work with @RestController everything works fine, when with a regular @Controller, to go to an html page, he writes that "You do not have rights to view this page." although the address in the filter is indicated in a white sheet, what could be the matter? I looked on the Internet, it says that @RestController and @Controller differ in the annotation @ResponseBody, but one works, the other does not.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final String[] availablePages = new String[] {
            "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700",
            "page/registration",
            "act/registration",
            "page/unregistered",
            "act/unregistered",
            "/api/v1/auth/**",
            "/rest/registration",
            "/registration",
            "",
    };

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter,
                 AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.jwtAuthFilter = jwtAuthFilter;
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean // связывание фильтра со Spring App
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity 
    httpSecurity)
            throws Exception { //build()

        httpSecurity
                .csrf() //in diff video
                .disable()
                //filter white list
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(availablePages)//should not be filtered
                .permitAll() //patterns
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                //filter use before auth pass filter
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }

}
```

WORK

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestAuthenticationController {

    // кодирует информацию при регистрации, по раскодировке можно
    // получить данные на JWT сайте (дату)

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(
        @RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticate(request));

    }


}
```

DON'T WORK

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/page")
public class PageController {

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String toRegistrationPage() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @GetMapping("/unregistered")
    public String toUnregisteredUserPage() {
        return "unregistered.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registered")
    public String toRegisteredUserPage() {
        return "registered.html";
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>security</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurity2_2023</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurity2_2023</name>
    <description>SpringSecurity2_2023</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        //генерируется автоматически, нажав на new Interface()
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                //проброс ошибки в случае если пользователь не найден
                //repository always return Optional<>!
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!"));
    }

    @Bean // отвечает за предоставление данных
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        //pass encoder
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean //тоже нужен
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager
            (AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean //pass encoder
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but I seem to have the right controller anyway, and if the problem is in Security, then I didn't find anything

Comment: Can you please specify which endpoint are you trying to access, for which you got the error? Also, In the spring @Configuration class, I can see that you have directly used `jwtAuthFilter` and `authenticationProvider` which are neither `@Autowired` nor their values set explicitly, so are references seem to be null.

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly, the fact is that I can't find where the error occurs, when I was debagging, I put a breakpoint on the filter and the controller itself, but it doesn't stop anywhere, writes "You don't have rights to view this page." in the browser. I also added the @Autowired annotation in the constructor

Comment: I wanted to ask which api(endpoint e.g. /page/registration) are you trying to access? Also, if you try to access an endpoint and put a debugger on other API, then the code wont reach at the debugger and hence never stops. (e.g. you might have put a debugger on /page/registration and trying to access /page/registered. Let me know if you have a github repo.

Comment: yes, I am trying to access /page/registration or to any other html page, github: https://github.com/NikitaMozolevsky/SpringSecurity21_2023

Answer (score 0):

Some problems that I see in your github repo:

1. You do not have `@Controllers` or `@RestControllers` in your application. Please add them
2. In your `SecurityConfiguration` class you have not provided any API in `requestMatchers()`. So ideally it will not allow any API to be accessed. If you want to exclude any API, put it inside the method.
3. In your `SecurityConfiguration` class you have not provided a way for user to login via browser and you are likely to get the same error.

> "You do not have rights to view this page."

If you want to get a spring generated login page, use `formLogin()` method, something like this:

```
    httpSecurity.csrf() 
                ......
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, at the time when you were watching git, I hadn't done push yet, now there is a controller there, probably that's why there were no requestMatchers, and I also don't need a page generated by spring, I already have my own, and I want it to work, and if you can explain what it means " you have not provided a way for user to login via browser", if this is a web application, how to do it?

Comment: In `SecurityConfiguration`  class, use `/page/registration` instead of `page/registration`. You don't seem to be using authenticationManager() but you have defined it.  Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71449312/9462050) on how to use it, if you really want to. Also, you changed most of the code, which is not how you ask here ig.