# csrf protection in jsp from where controller method has been called

Tags: spring-mvc, csrf

How can I achieve csrf protection where I am calling controller from jsp like this.

`href="/report/test.do?action=test"`

I am using Spring 3.1 MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Have You considered adding spring security. It by default add sf and csrf protection. If you dont use spring security then you have to write your own code for csrf protection You can check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500332/spring-security-and-json-authentication/27728235#27728235) for spring security

Comment: @Sazzad thanks for you help..but this not what am looking exactly.I have already done csrf protection but that doesn't support when the request is "GET".I have used the csrf token in a hidden field for normal jsp.But I need to do the protection on particular action which is mention above