# Where do i put check for authentication in spring UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am passing username and password from client application through json object and i am using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter for authenticating user as suggested in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572145/4070142 of question [Spring Security and JSON Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500332/spring-security-and-json-authentication).

My question is that where do i put check for authentication? I mean where do i put `if(username.equals("user123")&&password.equals("password123")) {return true;}`

For code please refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572145/4070142 of above linked question.

Comment: You don't. That is what spring security is doing for you,

Comment: Yeah, Thats true, But somewhere we need to configure like in <authentication-manager> tag in configuration file. So if i put manually valid user credentials in <authentication-manager> tag then how do i link it with my custom filter <custom-filter> tags?

Comment: You give it an alias, and inject it into your filter. Although I wouldn't go for the solution you have in the other thread. Nor would I link to that thread but provide all the information here, it isn't really nice to have the people who want to help you click around to get all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Actual username and password comparisons happen at authentication provider. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter obtains username/pwd and passes on to authenticationManager, which inturn delegates it to authenticationProvider. In your case, you need to add a custom authentication provider as follows:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if(username.equals("user123") && password.equals("password123")) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")); //assign some role
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth; //return Authentication object, not true
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

declare the new authentication provider in our configuration:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Reference:
https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/