# Username and Password not mapping with Authentication in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE version and it's custom Authentication Login application. But I'm facing issue

First take a look on code

**CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
@Qualifier(value = "customAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{


public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws     AuthenticationException {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);


    Role r = new Role();
    r.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    roles.add(r);


    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles;
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
}

public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return true;
}

}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}

//.csrf() is optional, enabled by default, if using     WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter constructor
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
            .csrf();
}
}
```

**login.jsp**
Here is my Login page

```
  <form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.login(user)">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': loginForm.username.$invalid}">
            <input class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  type="text"
                   placeholder="Username" required ng-model="user.username" />
            <span class="help-block"
                  ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': loginForm.password.$invalid}">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" id="password" type="password"
                   placeholder="Password" required ng-model="user.password" />
            <span class="help-block"
                  ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                    value="Login" title="Login" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid">
                <span>Login</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

On authenticate() in CustomAuhtenticationProvider class

1. authentication.getCredentials();
2. authentication.getName();

both giving empty string , but I need username and password in this.

[image: Here is IntellijIdea Debug screen shot]

Here is my AngularJS Service

**Service.js**

```
  function loginUser(user) {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'csrf_token': csrfToken
        }
    }


    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post("/login", user,config)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while creating User');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm using AngularJS and it's included inside  Service

Comment: Uhm... how are you sending the username and password? Common form parameters or in any other format such as json?

Comment: I know, that's why I told you to try disabling csrf(), as in the form does not appear the csrf token. As @M.Deinum said, include your angular controller or at lease the login request message format. I bet you are sending as json

Comment: AngularJS provide by default json format for form submission.
 why would you need your own provider, which doesn't even do something?
bcz I need my own authentication rather than LDAP , DAO or in memory authentication

Comment: it's already @Naman

Comment: can you copy xml configuration if you have done any?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending authentication credentials as JSON and you are using the default [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java) that tries to retrieve the authentication credentials from the HttpServletRequest parameters.

They will always be null. You must build your own custom Filter which takes the authentication credentials from the json received in the request body instead of from http params.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39034883/4190848)

**EDIT:** The fact is that you are not getting the login credentials you sent from your Angular controller. The reason is probably that if you are sending them as json in the request body you cannot rely on the default UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, as it tries to build the Authentication object reading the HttpServletRequest parameteres.

public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends
        AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        ...
}

/**
     * Enables subclasses to override the composition of the password, such as by
     * including additional values and a separator.
     * <p>
     * This might be used for example if a postcode/zipcode was required in addition to
     * the password. A delimiter such as a pipe (|) should be used to separate the
     * password and extended value(s). The <code>AuthenticationDao</code> will need to
     * generate the expected password in a corresponding manner.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param request so that request attributes can be retrieved
     *
     * @return the password that will be presented in the <code>Authentication</code>
     * request token to the <code>AuthenticationManager</code>
     */
    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(passwordParameter);
    }

    /**
     * Enables subclasses to override the composition of the username, such as by
     * including additional values and a separator.
     *
     * @param request so that request attributes can be retrieved
     *
     * @return the username that will be presented in the <code>Authentication</code>
     * request token to the <code>AuthenticationManager</code>
     */
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
    }
```

You should extend this filter, override attemptAuthentication() method to avoid calling the obtainUsername and obtainPassword while recovering this credentials. Instead, write a custom method where you will read the [ServletRequest's InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--) and parse to object using the json library you used to. I usually use jackson [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724932/4190848)

Comment: Take a look on attached picture ;I'm not getting null value it's empty string .