# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in spring Security doesn't get invoke

Tags: spring, spring-security, kotlin

I wanted to pass in JSON instead of using params while logging in. So what I do is I create a filter, however, the strange thing is that the filter itself doesn't get invoke at all (Or basically when I try logging in, the request by pass it, completely ignore my filter). The request go straight to my AuthenticationHandler. I have gone through many posts and I still have no clue of why would this happen, especially when I replicate the same structure of code in Java but it works perfectly as intended...

Did I miss something obvious? Here's the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and my security config. My Java version works fine, but my Kotlin version completely ignores the filter.

It doesn't return 404 as well, it returns my AuthenticationFailureHandler.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import lombok.Getter
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.charset.Charset

class JsonLoginFilter : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

     @Throws(AuthenticationException::class)
     override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse?): Authentication {
         if (!HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.method)) {
            throw AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.method)
         }

         val payload: String
         try {
              payload = IOUtils.toString(request.inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset())
              val auth = ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, JsonAuthenticationParser::class.java)
             // println(auth.username)
             // println(auth.password)
              val authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.username, auth.password)
              return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest)
         } catch (e: IOException) {
              throw InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Could not parse authentication payload")
         }

    }

    @Getter
    data class JsonAuthenticationParser @JsonCreator
    constructor(@param:JsonProperty("username")
                 val username: String,
                @param:JsonProperty("password")
                 val password: String)
    }
```

My Security config in Kotlin

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler

@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurity: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var entryConfig: EntryConfig

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var failAuth: FailAuthentication

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var successAuthentication: SuccessAuthentication

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var authenticationHandler: AuthenticationHandler

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/traveller/add","/api/v1/symptoms","/api/v1/flights","/api/v1/user/login","/api/v1/user/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/**","/api/v1/traveller/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(authenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/user/login")
                .successHandler(successAuthentication).failureHandler(failAuth)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryConfig)
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/api/v1/user/logout")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()


        //

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
    }


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationHandler)
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun authenFilter(): JsonLoginFilter {
        var filter : JsonLoginFilter = JsonLoginFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successAuthentication)
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failAuth)
        return filter
    }


    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

}
```

My Java version, slightly differ but I believe it should have the same structure

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class JsonAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("hello");
        if (! HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.getMethod())) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String payload;
        try {
            payload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
            JsonAuthenticationParser auth = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, JsonAuthenticationParser.class);
            System.out.println(auth.username);
            System.out.println(auth.password);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.username, auth.password);

            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Could not parse authentication payload");
        }
    }

    @Getter
    static class JsonAuthenticationParser {
        private final String username;
        private final String password;

        @JsonCreator
        public JsonAuthenticationParser(@JsonProperty("username") String username, @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

Security config in Java

```
import hard.string.security.AuthenticationHandler;
import hard.string.security.EntryConfig;
import hard.string.security.FailAuthhentication;
import hard.string.security.SuccessAuthentication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntryConfig entryConfig;

    @Autowired
    private FailAuthhentication failAuth;

    @Autowired
    private SuccessAuthentication successAuthentication;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler;

    @Bean
    public JsonAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        JsonAuthenticationFilter filter = new JsonAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
//        filter.setContinueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication(true);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successAuthentication);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failAuth);
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500332/spring-security-and-json-authentication

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/register",
                        "/debug/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(successAuthentication).failureHandler(failAuth)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryConfig)
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll();


        //

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, After spending days to find the bug. I found out that the filter doesn't automatically link with loginProcessingUrl. You need to specify what url you want to do the filter on or else it will just apply the filter only to localhost:xxxx/login

I just going to leave this question up here just in case someone run into this stupid problem like myself.

```
fun authenFilter(): JsonLoginFilter {
        var filter : JsonLoginFilter = JsonLoginFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successAuthentication)
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failAuth)
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/user/login") //HERE
        return filter
    }
```